# Calculating return on investment including short sell

Tags: r, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I am trying to calculate return on investment for stocks.  I think this is right, but don’t know how to test for accuracy.
The code calculates several things: return on investment: (close to close), buy on close sell next day on open, short sell, short sell day trading.  Maybe this will make it clearer:

```
    library(quantmod)
    library(PerformanceAnalytics)
    getSymbols('F', src='yahoo',from='2015-01-01')
    data <- get('F')
    adjD <- adjustOHLC(data, symbol.name='F')

    #calculate normal investment return
    clcl <- Delt(Lag(Cl(adjD)), Cl(adjD), type='log')
    chart.CumReturns(clcl)

    #calculate after hours, from prev. day close to next day open
    clop <-  Delt(Lag(Cl(adjD)), Op(adjD), type='log')
    chart.CumReturns(clop)

    #then to calculate stock short
    clopSh <-  Delt(Cl(adjD), Lag(Cl(adjD)), type='log')
    chart.CumReturns(clopSh)

    #then to calculate day trade short, sell open to buy close
    opclSh <-  Delt(Cl(adjD), Op(adjD), type='log')
    chart.CumReturns(opclSh)
```

Suggestions?  Especially concerned how I am calculating short sell.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply the return by -1.

ROC(adjD,type='discrete)*-1

A short return (ignoring costs to borrow) is the same return as long just multiplied by -1